# Data structure to store ip addresses

Tags: c#, data-structures

What is the best data structure to store a list of client's ip addresses?

I think there are no any strict limitations on memory size or lookup speed since it is a ip address filter application.

I was thinking about dictionary, but probably it is gives too much overhead for storing such a  simple thing as unique list of addresses. Hashtable is essentially based on dictionaries as well.

Array is not good because you have to allocate too much space even for storing few addresses. 
List is not unique.

Comment: Have a look at [How to store IP address list in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386576/how-to-store-ip-address-list-in-c-sharp-list-to-make-it-searchable-for-subnets-t)

Comment: Use list. Ovveride list.Add function to check before adding ip to list to keep the uniqueness. i.e. if(!list.contains(this_ip)) list.Add(this_ip)

Comment: I think you're overestimating the overhead involved with a hash table.

Comment: @Dukeling: Last time I did the profiling, `HashSet<T>` required something like 24 bytes per entry. See http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/21/more-on-net-collection-sizes/

Comment: The answer will depend in large part on how many IP addresses you're talking about. If it's a few dozen, a `List<T>` or array would probably be fine. Up to a few million, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `HashSet<T>` would be hard to beat. It also depends on if you expect to be adding things often, or if the list is relatively static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want uniqueness you can use

```
HashSet<IPAddress>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a try!